# Initial value problem-unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could anyone help me to solve this exercise?

$${y}'=\sqrt{\left | y \right |}$$
$${y(0)=1/4}$$
$${t}\epsilon{[0,2]}.$$
Show that the initial value problem has a unique solution.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: $\LaTeX$ tip: use "\in"

Answer (score 1):

The function $g(y) = \sqrt{|y|}$ is Lipschitz on $[1/10, \infty)$, so your ODE has a unique solution for small $t > 0$.  Since $y(t)$ is increasing, the ODE has a unique solution for $t \geq 0$.